# "Whether" or "how"?

Tags: word-choice

I read a sentence in "The Hindu" which was:

Further, it is unclear how tenant farmers, those without titles, and women farmers would be within the ambit of the scheme.

Shouldn't there be "whether" instead of "how"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [1] *Further, it is unclear* [***how*** tenant farmers, those without titles, and
>   *women farmers would be within the ambit of the scheme*].
>
> [2] *Further, it is unclear* [***whether*** tenant farmers, those without titles,
>   *and women farmers would be within the ambit of the scheme*].

Both constructions are possible, though they have different meanings.

The bracketed expressions are subordinate interrogative clauses (embedded questions).

[1] is an 'open' interrogative, which questions the way (or the manner in which) the farmers would be within the ambit of the scheme. The meaning is:

*“The answer to the question ‘How would tenant farmers, those without titles, and women farmers be within the ambit of the scheme?’ is unclear.”*

[2], by contrast, is a 'closed' interrogative, which questions the possibility of the farmers being within the ambit of the scheme. The meaning is:

*“The answer to the question ‘Will tenant farmers, those without titles, and women farmers be within the ambit of the scheme?’ is unclear.”*